# Getting Mixed Up With Limit Notation and Sequence Notation.

Tags: real-analysis

Suppose I have the following sequences $(x_n)$ and $(y_n)$ who's $n^{th}$ terms are defined by:

$$ x_n = \dfrac{1}{n} $$
$$ y_n = 7n $$

I think it's fairly apparent that $x_n \rightarrow 0$ while $y_n \rightarrow \infty$

However, the sequence $(x_n y_n) \rightarrow 7$ and if I wrote the following in limit notation:

$$ \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty}x_ny_n = \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty}x_n \thinspace \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty}y_n = 0 \thinspace \infty $$but what if I wrote...

$$ \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty}\dfrac{1}{n}\thinspace 7n = \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty}7 = 7 $$

So I am confused here as to why the product of the sequences could go to 7, but the product of the limits would be indeterminant.

Comment: This is a perfect example of why the limit of a product isn't the product of the limits (unless, both limits exists).

Comment: Yeah so I 'feel' like I understand your comment, but I think the heart of my problem is understanding the differences in the notation that are leading to my confusion.

Comment: $\displaystyle \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty}y_n$ doesn't exists, so $\displaystyle \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty}x_ny_n = \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty}x_n  \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty}y_n$ is false.

Comment: But would you agree that how I wrote the sequence notation works? and if so, in what way is it different then the limit notation?

Comment: The correct computation is $\lim_n \frac1n7n = \lim_n 7 = 7$ and not $\lim_n \frac1n7n = \big(\lim_n \frac1n\big) \big(\lim_n 7n \big)$, since the equation $\lim_n x_ny_n = \lim_n x_n \lim_n y_n$ is not always true. There are no two ways of doing this.

Comment: I do appreciate the feedback, but I do not think you are fully understanding where my confusion is coming from.

Comment: You are simply not allowed to use the rule $\lim x_n y_n = \lim x_n \lim y_n$ unless the two limits on the right exist as finite real numbers.